# 'Bundle.GetParcelable(string?)' is obsolete: 'deprecated'

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin, visual-studio-2022

So I have this obsolescence issue using VS 2022 Xamarin and android api 33 (Triamisu), I don't want to use the `[Obsolete]` key word as although the app works fine on my Samsung S21 (Android v13) phone, eventually all support for earlier versions of android will drop off and I will have to update all my code anyway.  So in the interest of getting ahead of this, I'm putting the question out there.

Currently my code is:

```
User MyUser = new User("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "");
MyUser = bundlee.GetParcelable("MyUser") as User;
```

I move the user data from one activity to another so I don't have to make another call to the database, hopefully saving time.  I read the article [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle) and can't really figure out what syntax I need in order to correct the code.  `User` is a class defined in my code and I populate an instance of the class with the user's data.  I move the data from one activity to another like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(Menu));
Bundle bundlee = new Bundle();
bundlee.PutParcelable("MyUser", MyUser); // Persist user class to next activity
intent.PutExtra("TheBundle", bundlee);
StartActivity(intent);
```

Now apparently things are changing and I cannot figure out how to adapt my code to the change.  There isn't a lot of information out there as this is a recent change, I've read the android developer documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#getParcelable(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%3CT%3E)) but it wasn't much help.  What `class clazz` do I use in this instance?  I created the class I'm passing in c#, so it's not java.  I'm very confused.  Can anyone clear this up for me?

Comment: I can only assume you are compiling your code and you are getting a warning with a message that serves as the title for this question?

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: The downvotes do not necessarily reflect the legitimacy of the question. It probably has more to do with how the question and it's details are presented.

Comment: You wrote three paragraphs of text to essentially ask “what is the correct syntax for this API call?”

Comment: What language are you writing this code in?

Comment: I use VS 2022 and code in c#.

Comment: @jason I wrote three paragraphs to explain why I was asking for the correct syntax.  I felt that was necessary as the code as written works.

Comment: context is great, but in this case (IMO) it just obscured the fairly straightforward question you were actually asking

Comment: FWIW: Never assume people will click on links: a question should *stand on its own*. The question would be clearer if it included the java function syntax, for which you are trying to figure out the c# equivalent: `getParcelable(String key, Class<T> clazz)`. Without that, its a lot of words, that never quite say what API method you are trying to call. ALSO, when there is an error or warning, **include the full text of the error or warning**. Here, that would have shown the "safer" call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick look at the source code (available online) confirms what you are experiencing:

```
/* @deprecated Use the type-safer {@link #getParcelable(String, Class)} starting from Android
*      {@link Build.VERSION_CODES#TIRAMISU}.
*/
@Deprecated
@Nullable
public <T extends Parcelable> T getParcelable(@Nullable String key) {
  //Implementation here
}
```

As you can see, the comment is recommending you use the other (type-safer) method instead:

```
/**
 * Returns the value associated with the given key or {@code null} if:
 * <ul>
 *     <li>No mapping of the desired type exists for the given key.
 *     <li>A {@code null} value is explicitly associated with the key.
 *     <li>The object is not of type {@code clazz}.
 * </ul>
 *
 * <p><b>Note: </b> if the expected value is not a class provided by the Android platform,
 * you must call {@link #setClassLoader(ClassLoader)} with the proper {@link ClassLoader} first.
 * Otherwise, this method might throw an exception or return {@code null}.
 *
 * @param key a String, or {@code null}
 * @param clazz The type of the object expected
 * @return a Parcelable value, or {@code null}
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Nullable
public <T> T getParcelable(@Nullable String key, @NonNull Class<T> clazz) {
    // The reason for not using <T extends Parcelable> is because the caller could provide a
    // super class to restrict the children that doesn't implement Parcelable itself while the
    // children do, more details at b/210800751 (same reasoning applies here).
    return get(key, clazz);
}
```

The new method even has a comment as to why you want to use this instead.

Notice this in particular:

> - @param clazz The type of the object expected

So, to answer your question, it looks like you should be doing this to get the object:

```
User MyUser = new User("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "");
MyUser = bundlee.GetParcelable("MyUser", Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(User))) as User;
```

Or:

```
MyUser = bundlee.GetParcelable("MyUser", Java.Lang.Class.FromType(MyUser.GetType())) as User;
```

Comment: Both lines of code generate the same error, `cannot convert from 'System.Type' to 'Java.Lang.Class'`.  It would seem that the call requires a `Java.Lang.Class`, I guess the question is "What java.lang.class"?  I can't find any information on "java.lang.class" and what they are.

Comment: @PrescottChartier there is a library to perform this conversion that is part of the SDK. I have updated my answer to reflect this. Please take another look.

Comment: I can accept the answer in terms of the syntax, but there's more to it than that.  One has to now be aware of the api version of the phone that the app is installed on.  My test device is api 31, so this syntax causes the app to crash.  I added an api version check to my code and it woks fine, but I have no way to (yet) test this against api 33.

Comment: @PrescottChartier interesting. I am glad you found it useful. You might benefit from a tool like [BrowserStack](https://www.browserstack.com/).

Comment: I checked out BrowserStack, they don't yet have API 33 but looks like a good place to test apps.  I'll be sure to check it out once they have API 33.  They said it would be "soon".

Comment: @JaunR And now there's this issue.  Although the syntax is correct, the call at runtime causes the error `Java.Lang.NullPointerException: 'Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.Class.isInterface()' on a null object reference'`.  The problem is apparently a bug in the API, you can see that here at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/240585930.  They reccomend that one use the depreciated syntax as it still functions as intended.

Comment: Tell me about it.  I'm on the trail of converting my code to use the ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture() which is what I'm trying to do with this app, I can't find anything in c# and java is a total mystry to me.  I don't suppose you can assist?

Comment: @PrescottChartier I created this room so we can discuss: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250337/android-api-conversion